# correct syntax for json in github command from terminal

Tags: json, curl, command-line, github, terminal

How can I change this curl command to make it work
It is something about using the $@ param that github starts complaining

```
function create_repo(){
  curl -u 'USER' https://api.github.com/user/repos -d '{"name":$@}'
}
```

It works if I hardcode the param as a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command uses a singly-quoted string, inside which variables are usually not interpolated (though you haven't specified a particular shell).

Try this instead:

```bash
function create_repo(){
  curl -u 'USER' https://api.github.com/user/repos -d "{\"name\":\"$@\"}"
}
```

Note that we use `\"` instead of `'` for our inner quotes because JSON requires double quotes.

Comment: I actually had to put quotes around the parameter also. -- "{\"name\":\"$@\"}"